# Angular - bind and run service function in DOM element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my `$scope.displaySeq` function I need to bind the function `lightIt.creatRipple` from my service `lightIt` to `seqId` object and call it. When I call  `seqId.lightUp` which contains `lightIt.createRipple` it does nothing. For testing purposes Press the start button to run `$scope.displaySeq`. Here is the codepen link http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/ZQXdJo?editors=101

```
simonApp.service('lightIt', [function(){
  var self = this;
      function getPosition(element) {
          var xPosition = 0;
          var yPosition = 0;

          while(element) {
              xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
              yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
              element = element.offsetParent;
          }
          return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
      }


      this.createRipple = function(e,pad){
        var y,x,leftOffset,topOffset;
        if(e !== undefined){
          findPos = getPosition;
          leftOffset = findPos(pad).x;
          topOffset = findPos(pad).y;
          x = e.pageX - leftOffset;
          y = e.pageY - topOffset;
          y = y + 'px';
          x = x + 'px';  
        }else{
          y = '80px';
          x = '80px'; 
        }

        var circle = pad.querySelector('.ripple-circle');
        circle.style.top = y;
        circle.style.left = x;

        var cRipple = pad.querySelector('.ripple');
        cRipple.classList.add('is-active');
        setTimeout(function() {
              cRipple.classList.remove('is-active');
          }, 500);
      }  
      /*
      this.endRipple = function(pad){
        var cRipple = pad.querySelector('.ripple');
        cRipple.classList.remove('is-active');
      };
      */
}]); 

$scope.displaySeq = function(sequenceArg) {
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var seqId = pads[sequenceArg[i]];
        seqId.lightPad = function() {
          lightIt.createRipple(this);
        }.bind(seqId);
        console.log(seqId);
        console.log(seqId.lightPad);
        seqId.lightPad;
        i++;
        if (i >= sequence.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
   }, speed);

}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Not sure what we should be looking for in demo

Comment: When I start the game one of the four `pad`'s should show a ripple effect but that is not happening. I bind the ripple effect to one of the pads and it should call the ripple effect with `seqId.lightPad` when I press start.